# DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER error

Tags: ssis

My package consists of dynamic db connections. When i run my package it is throwing error like  DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "conn" failed with error code 0xC0202009.

I tried setting delay validation property to true at package level.

I tried to change Package Protection Level property to EncryptSensitiveWithpassword. Still am facing with same error.

Am able to run the package manually.

How to get rid of this.

Comment: am able to solve my problem, i removed the old connection manager and created new one. And mapped the new one. This solved my problem

Comment: You should post your comment as an answer and then accept it so others can find a solution if they have a similar problem.

Comment: This happen because the connection manager is not included in the SSIS package or because the connection manager is not able to connect to the data source?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This can be solved in 2 ways

First, i have changed my delay validation property at package level to **True** from false.

Change ProtectionLevel to **EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey**.

Second, Remove the old connection manager and create new one.

Most of the time first way solves the problem.

Comment: why do you think it was happening ?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the package to Package deployment model
Please create a Package configuration file for the Connection String. Save the password here.
When you deploy the package to a separate environment, copy the package along with the configuration file. Make sure the path in local and new environment is the same.
This solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I had this error keep reappearing because I forgot my connection string was created on the fly using variables and an expression (see image).  Once I edited the connection string there then this error went away.[image: connection string]

Answer (score 0):

I have added port number along with the DB name and added Provider as SQLNCLI11 in dts(config file) and added port number along with the IP address in the dtsx file(SSIS package) and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to assign/grant the user that's executing the package the required privileges to act on the databases used in the packages.