# SSIS Deployment: SSIS Package run time error in SQL Server deployment

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis, ssis-2012

I am new in working with SSIS on SQL server. I deployed a package to my Test Server and trying to execute in Intergration service catalog to run the package and these are the errors i see every time i run it. I tried to schedule a job to run this and even that failed. I researched online but nothing helped. Any suggestions are welcomed. The package runs fine in BIDS. Thanks

> Error:1  Trip:Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB
>   error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D. An OLE DB record is
>   available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" 
>   Hresult: 0x80040E4D  Description: "Login failed for user 'NT
>   AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.".
>
> Error:2  Trip:Error: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The
>   AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager
>   "SourceConnectionOLEDB" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may
>   be error messages posted before this with more information on why the
>   AcquireConnection method call failed.
>
> Error:3 Trip:Error: Source_A_production failed validation and returned
>   error code 0xC020801C.
>
> Error:4  Trip:Error: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The
>   AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager
>   "SourceConnectionOLEDB" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may
>   be error messages posted before this with more information on why the
>   AcquireConnection method call failed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS connection manager login fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832456/ssis-connection-manager-login-fails)

Comment: There are a number of things that could be going on here. The first error message is the important one. Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON. It's some sort of a permissions issue, but that could be due to the environment, the login, the target server(s)...lots of things. Is/was the job running under a service account, or under your credentials after deployment?

Comment: the job is running under the service account @eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error 1:**

The user NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON does not required permissions to connect the DB. Please make sure that user has the rights to connect the targeter DB server.

**Error 2:**

The error says something is wrong with the credentials you are using to connect the db. Make sure your connection string looking like below:

```
"Provider=SQLNCL1;Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

If you have to use a username and password, make sure they are correct.

Also, you can try to change `ProtectionLevel` to `EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey`. If still does not work, try to create a new connection manager and delete the old one.

*References:*

- [SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER. The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager failed with error code 0xC0202009](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9757aeeb-df54-4f67-9df2-c5aa42502007/ssis-error-code-dtsecannotacquireconnectionfromconnectionmanager-the-acquireconnection-method?forum=sqlintegrationservices)
- [DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493189/dts-e-cannotacquireconnectionfromconnectionmanager-error)

**Error 3:**

Do a right click on project in Solution Explorer in debugging and look at the `Run64BitRuntime` property and toggle this to `false`.

*References:*

- [How to solve SSIS error code 0xC020801C/0xC004700C/0xC0047017](https://imgalib.wordpress.com/2013/01/24/how-to-solve-ssis-error-code-0xc020801c0xc004700c0xc0047017/)

**Error 4:**

Same as Error 2