# ODBC Connection cuts off randomly causing SSIS packages to fail

Tags: sql, oracle, ssis, odbc, connectivity

I discovered that a hand full of my SSIS population jobs were failing  due to the Following Error Message.

```
There was an error trying to establish an Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) connection with the database server.
```

[image: ScreenShot]

Different jobs have failed at roughly the same time of day (12:30 AM), but they will sometimes fail at other times of the day. Most of the time the jobs are successful. I'm unsure how to debug this issue since the it only fails occasionally. My DB admin doesn't seem to know what the issue is either. Is there a way to determine if the issue is on the SQL Server side or the Oracle side?

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493189/dts-e-cannotacquireconnectionfromconnectionmanager-error)

Please see if any of the solutions work.